# Issue in deploying spring cloud dataflow in Rancher

Tags: spring, kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow, rancher

I am trying to deploy spring cloud dataflow in Rancher. I am using the yaml files for deploying as mentioned in [this](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/kubectl/#deploy-skipper) link.

After deploying skipper server in Rancher. I am getting the following warning messages in logs:

> Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
> 2020-07-30 06:34:16.323 INFO 1 --- [nio-7577-exec-2] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888. Will be trying the next url if available 2020-07-30 06:34:16.323 WARN 1 --- [nio-7577-exec-2] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator :

> Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888//kubernetes": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused).

I am assuming the load balancer in Rancher is not getting provisioned because of this warning.

Answer (score 1):

The connection errors you see in your case can be ignored as it shouldn't fail to start the server (if it couldn't connect to Spring Cloud Config server - as it goes with the default settings).

You can also disable the spring cloud config by setting `spring.cloud.config.enabled` to `false`.